# How do I fix this truffle error: "Something already exists at the destination"?

Tags: truffle

```
$ truffle init
Downloading...
Error: Something already exists at the destination. `truffle init` and `truffle unbox` must be executed in an empty folder. Stopping to prevent overwriting data.
    at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\lib\utils\unbox.js:22:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Answer (score 1):

`truffle init` complains about the existence of *any* file in the folder, even hidden ones such as (on macOS) `.DS_Store`. Try `ls -A` to list all files from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, you need to delete the contents of the folder, or create a new empty folder, where you call `truffle init`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've checked that there aren't any extraneous files in your working directory, this error means you already have the `contracts`, `migrations`, and `test` directories, along with the relevant contents (smart contract, migration, and test scripts), within your working directory. If your working directory was empty instead, `truffle init` would have created these contents (initialized the project in the working directory) for you. You can just proceed with `truffle compile` assuming your already-initialized contents are bug-free.